# count users by there category and print category and number of users in category laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

```php
$users = User::select('count(*) as usersbycategory', 'categories.name as name')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', 'users.category_id')
        ->where('users.id', '!=', 1)
        ->orderBy('users.id', 'ASC')
        ->get()                        
        ->groupBy('users.category_id');
```

this is code in my controller and I am not getting results as I need

MySQL code that I want laravel

```sql
SELECT 
        COUNT(*) as usersbycategory, categories.name as name 
FROM `users` 
JOIN categories ON (categories.id = users.category_id) 
WHERE users.id != '1' 
GROUP BY users.category_id 
ORDER BY categories.id ASC;
```

Comment: What is your (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? PS Debug questions require a [mre]. Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please read the edit help re block code formats. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return CATEGORIES, why are you querying the User model? If you want to return categories just do it like this

```
Category::with('users')->withCount('users')->orderByDesc('users_count')->get();
```

This will return all the categories that have users, with the number of users from each category and ordered by that count.